# Correctly adding a repository / source / citation for a Burial as received by email

Tags: sources, citation, burial-records

Repositories, sources and citations still confuse me a lot. I know I have asked similar [questions](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15391/adding-source-citation-for-cremation) before. I have tried to take onboard that advice.

### Background

I wrote a letter to the **Cemeteries of Valencia** to find out details concerning my Great Grandfathers burial.

### Response

They kindly replied to me via email saying:

> Atendiendo su solicitud, adjunto remito escaneo del asiento en el
> libro de entierros de 1965, y lo trasncribo:
>
> 1965 enero día 25/ MIGUEL TORRES GIMENEZ/ 84 años/ Hemorragia Interna
> / juzgado 1. Hospital Clínico.
>
> Enterrado en la fosa común: Sección 7ª derecha/ cuadro 3/fila 14/letra
> G/lugar 3ª/ Judicial.
>
> (está debajo del cesped, no hay lápida)

Using DeepL this translates as:

> In response to your request, I enclose a scan of the entry in the 1965
> burial book, and I transcribe it:
>
> 1965 January 25th/ MIGUEL TORRES GIMENEZ/ 84 years old/ Internal
> Haemorrhage / Court 1. Hospital Clínico.
>
> Buried in the common grave: Section 7ª right/ box 3/ row 14/ letter G/
> place 3ª/ Judicial.
>
> (it is under the grass, there is no gravestone),

---

So I now have to create a repository, source and citation.

### Repository

The original address to write to was found [here](https://www.valencia.es/val/cementeris/localitzacio-de-difunts) (kindly provided in a comment to another answer on this site). So far I have input this for the repository:

- Name: Office of Cemeteries — Valencia
- Address: Oficina de Cementeris. Camí vell de Picassent, S/N (junt a Tanatori Municipal) - 46017 – València.
- Email: oficinadpd@valencia.es
- Note: Phone Number: 96.352.54.78

For some reason Ancestry would not allow me to add their number in the official phone number field. I could not format it correctly.

### Source

This is what I put for the source:

- Title: Office of Cemeteries — Valencia
- Author: Office of Cemeteries — Valencia
- Publisher: Office of Cemeteries — Valencia
- Publisher Location: Oficina de Cementeris. Camí vell de Picassent, S/N (junt a Tanatori Municipal) - 46017 – València.

### Citation

And the citation:

- Transcript:
  Atendiendo su solicitud, adjunto remito escaneo del asiento en el libro de entierros de 1965, y lo transcribo:

Fecha: 1965 enero día 25;
Nombres: MIGUEL TORRES GIMENEZ;
Edad: 84 años;
Enfermedades: Hemorragia Interna;
Juzgado: 1;
Parroquits: Hospital Clínico;

Enterrado en la fosa común:

Sección: 7ª derecha;
Cuadro: 3:
Fila: 14;
Letra: G;
Lugar: 3ª;

Observaciones: Judicial;

(está debajo del cesped, no hay lápida)

- Detail: Direct Email

I then attached the document as a PDF and linked it to the burial fact.

I feel that in this particular case I might not be doing this quite right. I know there are no rules as such and you can just do what you want but what I have done feels wrong. Guidance appreciated.

---

I have a feeling that I should be specifying "Burial Book of 1965" in a better way,